# Segfault inside of a fgetc while loop

Tags: c

I am having a little trouble with this code I am writing. I am able to get it to compile in other places but when I try to compile on my machine, I am running into a segfault.

Here is the error message I am receiving:

```
0x0000000000400dc6 in readFile (keyFileDir=0x401014 "k1.txt", 
plainTextFileDir=0x40101b "p1a.txt") at main.c:172
172                             key[j++] = tolower((char) i);
```

Here is the code:

```
FILE *keyFile;
FILE *plainTextFile;

keyFile = fopen(keyFileDir, "r");
plainTextFile = fopen(plainTextFileDir, "r");

fprintf(stdout, "\n\n");

if (keyFile == NULL) {
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "%s file not found, therefore we have no key.\n",
        keyFileDir);
    exit(0);
}
if (plainTextFile == NULL) {
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "%s file not found, therefore we have no plaintext.\n",
        plainTextFileDir);
    exit(0);
}

char *key, *plaintext;
int i, j, k, l = 0;

key = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10000);
plaintext = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10000);

while ((i = fgetc(keyFile)) != EOF) {
    if (i != ' ') {
        if ((i >= 'a' && i <= 'z') || (i >= 'A' && i <= 'Z')) {
            key[j++] = tolower((char)i);
        }
    }
}

key[j] = '\0';

while ((k = fgetc(plainTextFile)) != EOF) {
    if (k != ' ') {
        if ((k >= 'a' && k <= 'z') || (k >= 'A' && k <= 'Z')) {
            plaintext[l++] = tolower((char)k);
        }
    }
}

plaintext[l] = '\0';
```

For reference, I am feeding the strings "k1.txt" and "p1a.txt" as arguments. I am fairly new to C so I am sure it's a simple issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Your *compiler* is seg-faulting? Or does your attempt at running your *program* produce a seg-fault? The latter is on you; the former is something to be concerned about. `key[j++] = ...` invokes undefined behavior, btw. You never initialized `j`. And fyi, a *debugger* would likely break on the exact line of this fault, and give you the bonus of inspecting `j`, where you would have seen some odd value.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry about the incorrect verbiage. Initializing the j seems to be the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are probably assuming that`int i, j, k, l = 0;` initializes all of them as 0; but it doesn’t - only `l` is initialized.
You need to write `int i=0, j=0, k=0, l = 0;`

As a result, your `j` is a random value, and with `k[j] =`you are writing in a random place of memory, which is undefined behavior = crash.

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @Aganju is saying (you might be lucky and values might get initiated at 0 (back in my C days it was so on Sun Solaris for example), there is also the fact that you never limit your loop the the size of your buffers either, if the files you read are larger than your 10000 byte buffers, you might get into memory issues.

Comment: Ill keep this in mind. I don't believe the files Ill be using exceed 10000 byte buffers. Thanks!

Comment: *"you might get into memory issues"* - No "might" about it. If either `l` or `j` exceed `9999`, the program flat-out invokes undefined behavior. It's also unwise to assume `A`..`Z` is value-contiguous (and likewise `a`..`z`). [That isn't always the case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Code_page_layout).

Comment: Actually if you are extremely lucky (or unlucky, depending how you see it) and you go overboard by just a few bytes into memory that isn't really being used, nothing would crash. C isn't like Java there is no "ArrayOutOfBoundExceptions", unless you mess your stack and/or go outside your program's protected memory space, everything will seem ok.

Comment: @WhozCraig , specifically _that_ (a-z, A-Z are each contiguous) is guaranteed by the language specification.

Comment: @Aganju Maybe we're talking about different things. Digits characters are guaranteed contiguous by the language; (ex: x = '9' - '5';` will result in `x = 4`). That is not the case for the alphabet in general. The folly, therefore, is assuming that something greater or equal to `'A'` and lesser or equal to `'Z'` must be one of 26 distinct values. That isn't guaranteed. Will `'Z'` always be "greater" than `'A'` ? Sure (likely what you're referring to).  Honestly, the entire set of checks in the OP's code is pointless, as simply looping with direct assignment from `tolower` would be sufficient.